# Why two rows are being automatically selected in listview?

Tags: android, listview

My code has a ListView of notifications and when the user clicks on the notifications, its color changes. But my problem is that when the user clicks on the 1st row, another row color is also changing automatically same as for other rows.

```
notiId.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adpterView, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String sr_msg=arrayList.get(position);
            String sr_title= list_tittle.get(position);
            ArrayList<String> arr_intent = new ArrayList<String>();
            arr_intent.add(sr_msg);
            arr_intent.add(sr_title);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotiPerList.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("NOTI", (Serializable) arr_intent);
            intent.putExtra("NOTI",arr_intent );
            startActivity(intent);
            String yn=arr2.get(position);
            String s2= arr3.get(position).toString();
            notiId.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        }

}
```

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View mView = v ;
    if(mView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }
    listView=(ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.notiID);
    String sd= yORn.get(position);
    if(sd.equals("Y")){
        mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: can't be a problem caused by the adapter that recycles the view that have background color changed?

Answer (score 1):

that's how `ListView` works. It is reusing views that go out of screen. Instead of changing view directly, you have to tell `Adapter` to change the color of specific index view.

Something like this:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adpterView, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

    ...
    yourAdapter.setHighLightedViewIntex(position);
    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

And in `Adapter`:

```
getView(...) {

    if(highlightedPosition == position) {
        //set background to highlighted
    } else {
        //set background to regular
    }
}
```

Comment: @chandra, i see. And what's next? What do you want me to do?

Comment: @chandra, I'd say you are missing `else` in your `if`

Comment: Actually i am very new to it..Could you please tell what i did wrong in my Adapter code..even i also given the condition

Comment: @chandra, you'd better learn ListView basics before statring using it. If you change something in the view by condition of it's position, then you have to change it back in `else` case since this view, with changed background will be reused for the other list items

Comment: actually problem is not that only even i am scrolling the listview without clicking any row its colour is getting changed..i am wondering

Comment: @chandra check this code given in Answer
`if(highlightedPosition == position) {
        //set background to highlighted
    } else {
        //set background to regular
    }`

add else like this

Comment: if(sd.equals("Y")){ mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  }else mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)  } @Harish i did like this but its not working for me.

Comment: What is yORn? Is it a Set? how you are adding values to yORn?

Comment: yORn is the arrayList in which i am storing the vale after fetching from server..it contains only Y or N

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
notiId.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

If your list has multiple selection then

1. Keep a HashSet object of type Integer
2. Add position in onItemClick method
3. Write condition in getView method that 
   if(set.contains(position))
          show other background 
   otherwise 
       show normal background

Comment: Listview will load first and then i can click on its row..i want the color should change when the listview loaded so that user can see if its already clicked or not.

Comment: When listview loads and setAdapter is called, its rows are loaded in getView method. no extra logic needs to write.